# Metadata with pdfcairo in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, metadata

I am producing graphs in gnuplot with pdfcairo terminal.

I would like to control metadata such like: title, subject, author, creation date, keywords. So far these fields are empty [Ninguno] or misquoted

Is that possible in gnuplot?

[image: Metadata in pdf file produced by pdfcairo in gnuplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a latex-derivated terminal (`epslatex`), embedded metadata formats (i.e. `hyperref` or Adobe's xmp module) are accessible with a latex preamble in the `set term` line.  The Cairo graphics library doesn't deal with metadata itself, you'll need to use some external tool.